# bounding the sum $\sum_{\exp((\log x)^{3/4})\le p\le x}\frac{1}{p^{1+it}}$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Can we prove that

$$\sum_{\exp((\log x)^{3/4})\le p\le x}\frac{1}{p^{1+it}}=o(\log\log x)$$

for $1\le t\le x$? Here $p$ runs over prime numbers.

Comment: when $t$ is not too large, it is not so different to $\displaystyle\sum_{exp(\log^{3/4}x) < n < x} \frac{1}{n^{1+it} \ln n}$